# On what microdata aggregate rating is based on

Tags: html, schema, microdata

I am integrating microdata for a website by using a [generator](http://microdatagenerator.com/generator.html) for the microdata but I can`t find information about the aggregate rating and on what it is based on.

Comment: What do you mean with "based on"? You are probably using the vocabulary Schema.org, right? So if your generator doesn’t offer the feature you need, you have to check Schema.org for a suitable type.

Comment: This generator has two fields about the rating - "Rating" and "Review count" which I have to fill but I can\`t find information about from where I have to get this values. Are those reviews coming from Google Plus or somewhere else?

Comment: It doesn’t matter where they are coming from (some external service, your own site, from letters you’ve received etc.). If you have ratings/reviews, you can mark them up; if you don’t have any, you don’t mark them up.

Comment: Ok thank you for the information it was really helpful.